# MySQL: Fetching rows added x hours

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Fetch rows for the past x hours. The problem is that x can be any amount of hours.For instance if x is 48, I need to get all the rows for the past 2 days. How can I store the `datetime` in the database and successfully retrieve the rows. Thank you. The user will select a date and time, then the duration(x).

Comment: Google search.try it

Comment: The thing is I dont need code. I just need to know how I should save the date and how can I then use something like DATE_SUB to get the data.

Comment: If you're saving dates and times, use the datatype `datetime`. You can use `>`, `<` and `BETWEEN` with datetime-columns in MySQL so the solution is really straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You may use DATE_SUB() function in mysql.

```
    *** WHERE `timecolumn_in_your_table` BETWEEN  ( DATE_SUB( '2016-08-17', INTERVAL 48 HOUR ) )  and '2016-08-17'
```

conditions can be given as per your requirement

Comment: so this query will get data between '2016-08-17' and 48 hours?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to alter your table to add a datetime field

`ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD timecolumn_in_your_table DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

Then, as Krishnakumar said, you can retrieve the rows using:

`*** WHERE timecolumn_in_your_table BETWEEN  ( DATE_SUB( '2016-08-17', INTERVAL 48 HOUR ) )  and '2016-08-17'`

(the upper where clause selects rows with `timecolumn_in_your_table` between 2016-08-15 00:00 and 2016-08-17 00:00)

(i wish i could add this post as a comment to Krishnakumar's answer, but i can not, as my reputarion rate is under 50)

Answer (score 0):

yes Jones. above query will give answers between particular date and sub(time interval from that date ). I hope this was what you asked.